# eventhandler not attaching to div elements created in a forloop

Tags: jquery, event-handling, user-input

I am trying to create a simple user interface consisting of an input text box that only accepts values from a 3X10 number pad grid 0-9 with the top row showing the number selected on the number pad. something like this to be exact[UI-interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7YYJ.png)

So far I have been able to create "divs" that I'll be using for buttons but they stack up on top of each other which I can play around with the styling using bootstrap and get the alignment working. I have been unable to attach the event listeners needed and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. below is my code. I am using jquery and bootstrap.

```js
function buildHtmlAndInteractions(init, lrnUtils) {
    //number pad structure
    // var $htmlObj = $('<table id="responsetable"><thead><input id="question_input" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 15:45" /><tr>...</tr></thead><tbody>');
    // var $htmlObj = $('<div class="container"><input id="question_input" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 15:45" /><div>...</div></div>')
    var $htmlObj = $('<div class="container-fluid">');
    var html = '<input id="question_input" type="text" value="">';
    var padLayout = [
        ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],
        ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"],
        ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
    ];
    for (let i = 0, len = padLayout.length; i < len; ++i) {
        html += `<div class="row">`;
        for (let j = 0, rowLen = padLayout[i].length; j < rowLen; ++j) {
            html += `<div class="col" textContent="${padLayout[i][j]}">` + padLayout[i][j] + `</div>`;
            var keys = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
            for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
                keys[k].addEventListener('click', logtoCon, false);
            }

            function logtoCon() {
                console.log(this.className);
            }
            console.log(keys);
        }
        html += '</div>';
    }
    html += '</div>';
    $(html).appendTo($htmlObj);
    return $htmlObj;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind eventListeners to actual elements on the page. As it is now, you're trying to create eventListeners on something that doesn't yet exist. `var keys = document.getElementsByClassName("col");` will be empty because at that point in your function, the elements have not yet been written to the page..

Just move the following lines OUT to the end of the function (after the appendTo() method which is what turns your string into actual HTML elements.

```
function buildHtmlAndInteractions(init, lrnUtils) {
    //.. all your code

    $(html).appendTo($htmlObj);

    var keys = document.getElementsByClassName("col");

    for(var k = 0; k<keys.length; k++){
       keys[k].addEventListener('click', logtoCon, false);
    }

    return $htmlObj; // not sure why you need this...
```

};

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! moving the code to the end did nothing, unfortunately. when I console.log (keys) weather near the end or where i had it originally, I see that I'm getting an HTML collection of 30 " div.col's "and I set the logtoCon function just to console.log a string("click") but nothing :(